# Convert Array String into JSON

Tags: java, json

I have list of values in an `Arraylist<String>` like this

```
Level1 | Level2
Level1 | Leve3
Level2 | Level4
Level4| Level5
Level4 | Level6
```

and I m finding it difficult how to convert these values into a JSON.
So JSON will look like this;

```
{ "Level1 ": "Level2",
 "subfolders": [{
  "Level2 ": "Level4",
  "subfolders": [{ 
  "Level4 ": "Level5"
   },
   { "Level4 ": "Level6"
    }] 
   },
  { "Level1 ": "Leve3" }] }
```

I just wanted to know the best way to approach this

Comment: The JSON looks like it got its data from a `Map` instead. Anyways, he best way to serialize to JSON is through a proper library like GSON or Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public String toJson(Object obj) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(obj);
  }
```

You can use this method for converting  objects to json, you need install Gson library.